Sas equivalent function to SQL Server group by cube
I have recently discovered the cool SQL Server group by cube function that summarize the result without a lot of coding.  Does SAS have the same without appending a lot of proc summaries.  Sample code:
Select Isnull(convert(varchar(8),load_date, 112), 'Total') as  Char_dates ,
Isnull(Product_code,'Total') as Product_codes,
Count(*) as volume, 
count(distinct cust_no) as Dist_Volume
from Database.dbo.table
group by cube( load_date, Product_code)

I have only been able to replicate the results if I append Proc summaries, but need the more and less classes that does not feel effective

SQL Server, not MySQL. GROUP BY CUBE is essentially a special case of ROLLUP, so you should look how to do rollups in SAS

This is not supported out of the box in PROC SQL, you could write a macro that mimics such functionality but would require as many passes through the data as you have groupings. There might be much more efficient solutions in PROC SUMMARY, see here.

Can you post example data and the desired output?  It looks like it should be straight forward with  a single PROC SUMMARY and a CLASS statement listing multiple variables.

Because of your COUNT(DISTINCT ....) you might need to use two steps.
First summarize by all THREE of your class variables.
 proc summary data=Database.table (schema='dbo') nway;
   class cust_no load_date Product_code;
   output out=step1;
 run;

Then you can add up the _FREQ_ variable from the first step to get your total Volume.
 proc summary data=step1 ;
    class load_date Product_code;
    output out=want sum(_freq_)=Volume n=Dist_Volume;
 run;

If you want the missing values to print as Total then define a format.  So assuming your LOAD_DATE variable has DATE values you might define the format to print them using the DATE9. format when not missing and Total otherwise.  And assuming your already have a PRODUCT format to print your PRODUCT_CODE values in a human friendly way you might make a format that just prints the missing values as Total and otherwise passes the values to the PRODUCT format to print.
 proc format;
    value date_total low-high=[date9.] other='Total' ;
    value product_total low-high=[product.] other='Total';
 run;

And then apply it when printing.
 proc print data=want;
    var load_date Product_code Volume Dist_Volume ;
    format load_date date_total. product_code product_total.;
 run;


This sounds a lot like what PROC MEANS does by default. For example:
proc means data=sashelp.cars noprint;
    class drivetrain origin;
    output out=foo
        mean(horsepower) = mean_horsepower;
run;

DriveTrain  Origin  _TYPE_  _FREQ_  mean_horsepower
                    0       428     215.88551402
            Asia    1       158     190.70253165
            Europe  1       123     251.89430894
            USA     1       147     212.82312925
    All             2       92      235.09782609
    Front           2       226     185.34070796
    Rear            2       110     262.57272727
    All     Asia    3       34      211.73529412
    All     Europe  3       36      249.72222222
    All     USA     3       22      247.27272727
    Front   Asia    3       99      171.67676768
    Front   Europe  3       37      210
    Front   USA     3       90      190.23333333
    Rear    Asia    3       25      237.44
    Rear    Europe  3       50      284.46
    Rear    USA     3       35      249.25714286

_TYPE_ defines which level of the roll-up it is.
0: Overall
1: Origin
2: Drivetrain
3: Drivetrain, Origin

You can control how many rollups you want with the ways option. For example, ways 1 says to only do 1-way combinations:
proc means data=sashelp.cars noprint;
    class drivetrain origin;
    ways 1;
    output out=foo
        mean(horsepower) = mean_horsepower;
run;

DriveTrain  Origin  _TYPE_  _FREQ_  mean_horsepower
            Asia    1       158     190.70253165
            Europe  1       123     251.89430894
            USA     1       147     212.82312925
All                 2       92      235.09782609
Front               2       226     185.34070796
Rear                2       110     262.57272727

You can customize this to add your own combinations. For example:
ways 0;
ways 0 2;
ways 1 to 4 by 2;
ways 1 to 4 by 2, 5;

